# Disable a method in a ViewSet, django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

`ViewSets` have automatic methods to list, retrieve, create, update, delete, ...

I would like to disable some of those, and the solution I came up with is probably not a good one, since `OPTIONS` still states those as allowed.

Any idea on how to do this the right way?

```python
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = api_models.Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = api_serializers.SampleSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
    def create(self, request):
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69648046

Answer (score 360, accepted):

The definition of `ModelViewSet` is:

```
class ModelViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, 
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, 
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                   mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   GenericViewSet)
```

So rather than extending `ModelViewSet`, why not just use whatever you need? So for example:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins

class SampleViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    ...
```

With this approach, the router should only generate routes for the included methods.

**Reference**:

[ModelViewSet](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/viewsets.py)

**Update**:
In DRF 3.14.0, using one of the methods not implemented in the mixins gives a `405 - Method Not Allowed`:

```bash
Method Not Allowed: /status/
[06/Mar/2023 01:03:01] "POST /status/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41
```

Comment: @SunnySydeUp Just trying this now and it seems the router does generate the route for a list view, but it 404s because the ViewSet doesn't know how to handle the request. Is this what you expected?

Comment: @stevejalim If you don't use the ListModelMixin, it shouldn't create the urlpattern for it. This is why it 404s I believe.

Comment: Looking at it, it actually 500s as a NoReverseMatch, which is less ideal than a 404

Comment: I just tested this and I did get a 404. Are you going to the URL through the browser or are you calling `reverse`? How did you set up your viewset?

Comment: By only using the mixins you need you can disable GET, POST, PUT, DELETE Methods but I did not able to find out how to disable the PATCH method specially if you are using routers.

Comment: @MuneebAhmad The PATCH method is enabled from the `UpdateModelMixin`. If you want to use update but not the patch, I can currently think of two ways. You can either override the allowed methods  in the view and remove "patch" or you can override the `partial_update` method and call `http_method_not_allowed(request, *args, **kwargs)`. I haven't tested this so I'm not sure if it works

Comment: @JulioMarins I've added a reference. I'm not sure if this is what you wanted though.

Comment: [@Akshar Raaj's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639113/disable-a-method-in-a-viewset-django-rest-framework#answer-31450643) looks much better for me

Comment: This does not seem to work as of DRF 3.9.0.  The dispatch tries to call the non-existent method (like `self.create` for a POST request) and then it raises an AttributeError.  The appropriate response would be to raise a 405.

Comment: If someone wants to make read-only viewset then they can use `class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet)`.

Answer (score 242):

You could keep using `viewsets.ModelViewSet` and define `http_method_names` on your ViewSet.

Example

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = api_models.Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = api_serializers.SampleSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head']
```

Once you add `http_method_names`, you will not be able to do `put` and `patch` anymore.

If you want `put` but don't want `patch`, you can keep `http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'head', 'put']`

Internally, DRF Views extend from Django CBV. Django CBV has an attribute called http_method_names. So you can use http_method_names with DRF views too.

[Shameless Plug]: If this answer was helpful, you will like my series of posts on DRF at https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/04/drf-polls/.

Comment: The problem with this way is no way to disable either list or retrieve. Have to disable both or neither

Comment: This did not work for me, after including get and head I was still able to do a post

Comment: This works for me on django 1.9. Great solution. Is there a risk users can do a GET request another way?

Comment: FANTASTIC solution. Works on `python3` and `Django 1.10` just fine.

Comment: I prefer this approach because I could not change the inheritance of mixins to include PATCH, but not PUT because they are both an implementation of  `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`

Comment: This is my ideal solution because it updates the HTTP methods in the auto-generated API documentation page :)

Answer (score 37):

Although it's been a while for this post, I suddenly found out that actually there is a way to disable those functions, you can edit it in the views.py directly.

Source: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewset-actions

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class NameThisClassWhateverYouWantViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def create(self, request):
        response = {'message': 'Create function is not offered in this path.'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    def update(self, request, pk=None):
        response = {'message': 'Update function is not offered in this path.'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
        response = {'message': 'Update function is not offered in this path.'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None):
        response = {'message': 'Delete function is not offered in this path.'}
        return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

Comment: This should be a preferrable way.

Comment: I think HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST would be more appropriate here if it is not related to auth.

Comment: What about `HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED`?

Comment: agree with @Ryan

Comment: I would also suggest using `raise MethodNotAllowed(request.method)`

Comment: If you disable `update` method, you're basically disabling `partial_update` too as it calls `update` at the end.

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to disable the PUT method from a DRF viewset, you can create a custom router:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

class NoPutRouter(DefaultRouter):
    """
    Router class that disables the PUT method.
    """
    def get_method_map(self, viewset, method_map):

        bound_methods = super().get_method_map(viewset, method_map)

        if 'put' in bound_methods.keys():
            del bound_methods['put']

        return bound_methods
```

By disabling the method at the router, your api schema documentation will be correct.

Comment: As partial patch is not correctly implemented within DRF it would be wise to remove it globally in the way described here

Comment: `bound_methods.pop('put', None)` would be more terse

Answer (score 6):

I liked @pymen answer's idea, but his implementation didn't work. This does:

```
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = [m for m in viewsets.ModelViewSet.http_method_names if m not in ['delete']]
```

This has the advantage of doing literally only exclusion and being simple. It looks sort of hacky though, but might be exactly what you need if it's only for that one ViewSet.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me in case of blocking only the method put not patch.

Answer (score 4):

The most straightforward way to disable a method on a viewset, keep things consistent across your api, and return a useful error message is to simply raise a MethodNotAllowed exception for any methods you do not want to use. For a method like GET that is mapped to retrieve and list with list being disabled, you could customize the error message to indicate that GET only works with a lookup value on the URL.

```
from rest_framework.exceptions import MethodNotAllowed

class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = api_models.Sample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = api_serializers.SampleSerializer

def list(self, request):
    raise MethodNotAllowed('GET', detail='Method "GET" not allowed without lookup')
def create(self, request):
    raise MethodNotAllowed(method='POST')
```

This will return a 405 status code and json data in the format DRF uses:

```
{'detail': 'Method "POST" not allowed.'}
```

Comment: If I want to apply a patch I will not be able to it.

Answer (score 4):

This is what i prefer.

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins

class ContentViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Content.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ContentSerializer
```

**ReadOnlyModelViewSet** - This will keep only readonly methods. Which are basically "GET" and "OPTIONS" requests.

**CreateModelMixin** - This will only allow creating of new elements. Which is "POST" request.

All other methods like "PUT", "PATH" and "DELETE" are disabled in above example. You can enable the various methods using mixins based on your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

**How to disable "DELETE" method for ViewSet in DRF**

```
class YourViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def _allowed_methods(self):
        return [m for m in super(YourViewSet, self)._allowed_methods() if m not in ['DELETE']]
```

*P.S. This is more reliable than explicitly specifying all the necessary methods, so there is less chance of forgetting some of important methods OPTIONS, HEAD, etc*

*P.P.S.
by default DRF has `http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace']`*

Comment: You can't call `super` on class level, there's no `self`.

Answer (score 3):

In Django Rest Framework 3.x.x you can simply enable every each method you want to be enabled for `ModelViewSet`, by passing a dictionary to `as_view` method. In this dictionary, the key must contain request type (GET, POST, DELETE, etc) and the value must contain corresponding method name (list, retrieve, update, etc). For example let say you want `Sample` model to be created or read but you don't want it to be modified. So it means you want `list`, `retrieve` and `create` method to be enable (and you want others to be disabled.)

All you need to do is to add paths to `urlpatterns` like these:

```py
path('sample/', SampleViewSet.as_view({
    'get': 'list',
    'post': 'create'
})),
path('sample/<pk>/', SampleViewSet.as_view({  # for get sample by id.
    'get': 'retrieve'
}))
```

As you can see there's no `delete` and `put` request in above routing settings, so for example if you send a `put` request to the url, it response you with 405 `Method Not Allowed`:

```
{
    "detail": "Method \"PUT\" not allowed."
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning to disable put/post/destroy methods, you can use

> viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet
> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#refactoring-to-use-viewsets

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach for Viewsets in django-rest-framework to enable/disable methods. Here is an example api/urls.py:

```
    user_list = UserViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'list'
    })
    user_detail = UserViewSet.as_view({
        'get': 'retrieve'
        'put': 'update',
        'post': 'create',
        'patch': 'partial_update',
        'delete': 'destroy'
    })


urlpatterns = [
    path('users/', user_list, name='user-list'),
    path('users/<int:pk>/', user_detail, name='user-detail')
]
```

View user_list has only one - get - method allowed, whereas user_detail has all methods active.

Tested on Django 4.0

reference: [more details here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/e7777cb1ee98c0215a5f1f082a88290eefa3e293/docs/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a little decorator:

```
def http_methods_disable(*methods):
    def decorator(cls):
        cls.http_method_names = [method for method in cls.http_method_names if method not in methods]
        return cls
    return decorator
```

It can then be used in different classes:

```
@http_methods_disable('patch', 'delete')
class SampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

@http_methods_disable('patch')
class AnyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a GenericViewSet, you have to explicitly define HTTP actions before using them. See [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#genericviewset) for more info.

Comment: It is often better to include some code example. this link will not working in the future maybe.