# How to Not allow the PUT method at all but allow PATCH in a DRF ViewSet?

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

`PUT` and `PATCH` are both part of the same mixin (The [UpdateModelMixin](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updatemodelmixin)).

So if I extend it like so:

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Both `PUT` and `PATCH` are allowed. I want to not allow `PUT` at all for my app (since `PATCH` already does the work, and I want to limit object creation using just `POST`). One way is to create a permission:

```
class NoPut(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    PUT not allowed.
    """
    message = 'You do not have permission to complete the action you are trying to perform.'

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if view.action == "update":
            return False
        return True
```

And to give this permission to all my ViewSets which allow `PATCH`. Is this the best way to do it? Is there a more preferred way?

Edit: After looking at the answer provided by @wim, will this be a fine solution (everything kept the same except the mapping for `put` was removed):

```
from rest_framework.routers import SimpleRouter
class NoPutRouter(SimpleRouter):

    routes = [
        # List route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create'
            },
            name='{basename}-list',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated list routes.
        # Generated using @list_route decorator
        # on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicListRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
            initkwargs={}
        ),
        # Detail route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                 # put removed
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy'
            },
            name='{basename}-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated detail routes.
        # Generated using @detail_route decorator on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicDetailRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
            initkwargs={}
        ),
    ]
```

or would I need to redefine other methods in `SimpleRoute` (e.g. `__init()__`, `get_routes()`, `_get_dynamic_routes()`, `get_method_map()` etc.) in order for it to work correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using `mixins.UpdateModelMixin` just define your own mixin that would perform patch only:

```
class UpdateModelMixin(object):
    """
    Update a model instance.
    """
    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = True
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_update(serializer)

        if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
            # If 'prefetch_related' has been applied to a queryset, we need to
            # forcibly invalidate the prefetch cache on the instance.
            instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

        return Response(serializer.data)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save()
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to use builtin `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`, limit to `PATCH` and disable swagger from showing PUT you can use `http_method_names`

```
class UserViewSet(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    http_method_names = ["patch"]
```

Comment: `http_method_names = ["patch"]` this worked, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

A simple and straight forward approach:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'patch'] # <---------
```

Like this the `PUT` method will not be allowed.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is so straight forward

Answer (score 1):

I think a superior solution would be to use a custom [router](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) and disable the route for PUT.  Then use your custom router for the viewsets.

```
class SimpleRouter(BaseRouter):
    routes = [
        # List route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'list',
                'post': 'create'
            },
            name='{basename}-list',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'List'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated list routes.
        # Generated using @list_route decorator
        # on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicListRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
            initkwargs={}
        ),
        # Detail route.
        Route(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            mapping={
                'get': 'retrieve',
                'put': 'update',
                'patch': 'partial_update',
                'delete': 'destroy'
            },
            name='{basename}-detail',
            initkwargs={'suffix': 'Instance'}
        ),
        # Dynamically generated detail routes.
        # Generated using @detail_route decorator on methods of the viewset.
        DynamicDetailRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{lookup}/{methodname}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{methodnamehyphen}',
            initkwargs={}
        ),
    ]
```

^ The router implementation looks something like that.  So you just need to inherit the `SimpleRouter`, or perhaps the `DefaultRouter`, and defines the `routes` class attribute how you want it.  You can remove the mapping for 'put' in the `Route(mapping={...})` completely, or you can define your own action to handle it and return the appropriate 400-something resonse.

Comment: Thanks. Okay so I edited my answer to include the new custom router. Can you verify that it is an okay custom router, or will I need to redefine other methods in `SimpleRouter` in order for it to work correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [@linovia's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43534772/4411196) but using standard mixin:

```py
from rest_framework.exceptions import MethodNotAllowed

class UpdateModelMixin(mixins.UpdateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    """
    update:
        Update Model
    """

    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise MethodNotAllowed("POST", detail="Use PATCH")

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Override Partial Update Code if desired
        return super().update(*args, **kwargs, partial=True)
```

Comment: This worked, but how to disable swagger from showing the PUT endpoint?

Comment: @TNT For [`drf-spectacular`](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular) you can use `@extend_schema_view(update=extend_schema(exclude=True))`

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I'm using:

```
class SomeViewSet(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    ...
):
    @swagger_auto_schema(auto_schema=None)
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Disabled full update functionality"""
        partial = kwargs.get('partial', False)  # This must be .get() not .pop()
        if not partial:
            raise exceptions.MethodNotAllowed(request.method)

        return super(SomeViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

This will also disable it in drf-yasg UIs.

Answer (score 1):

Solution similar to @EbramShehata's but for [`drf-spectacular`](https://github.com/tfranzel/drf-spectacular) (OpenAPI 3). This will disallow full updates (PUT) and also exclude that from the generated OpenAPI 3 schema.

```py
class SomeViewSet(
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    ...
):
    @extend_schema(exclude=True)
    def update(self, request: Request, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> Response:
        """Disallow full update (PUT) and allow partial update (PATCH)."""
        if kwargs.get("partial", False):  # Use .get() instead of .pop()
            return super().update(request, args, kwargs)

        raise MethodNotAllowed(request.method)
```