# Django REST shows non-allowed methods under Allow in the Browser

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

### Goal

Is to disable `OPTIONS` method globally.

#### Background

According to the official Django REST docs (https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/), the proper way to do it is to set `DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS` to `None`.

This resolves the problem. After trying to send the OPTIONS curl request, the server responds with the `405`.

#### Problem

However the API Browser would still show methods under *Allow* that are actually **not allowed**:

[image]

### Question

How to hide not-supported methods under *Allow* in Django API Browser?

Comment: You can override the `def _allowed_methods(self)` method.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639113/disable-a-method-in-a-viewset-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 1):

After checking the [Disable a method in a ViewSet, django-rest-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639113/disable-a-method-in-a-viewset-django-rest-framework), it turned out there are at least 3 good approaches to address this:

1. Use Specific ViewSets instead of just inheriting `ModelViewSet`
2. Overwrite _allowed_methods()
3. Define http_method_names()

It was decided to:

1. Set `DEFAULT_METADATA_CLASS` to `None` (to make sure non-defined methods are not exposed).
2. Define `http_method_names` for each ViewSet (to hide them in the Browser API).