# I Disabled a method in a ViewSet (django-rest-framework) but Swagger keep showing it in the documentation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, swagger, openapi-generator

I Disabled a method in a ViewSet (Retrive and List), but swagger (Open API) keep showing it in the documentation.

I tried this, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23639113/disable-a-method-in-a-viewset-django-rest-framework?rq=2):

```
def list(self, request):
    response = {'message': 'List function is not offered in this path.'}
    return Response(response, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
```

But its still present the endpoint.

Comment: are you using ModelViewSet class or ViewSet class?

Comment: I'm using a ModelViewSet

Comment: In that case, you should use GenericViewSet and mixins as per your need. because ModelViewSet by default provides all action. @daniel-ramos